# What keeps event loop open when listening for I/O events?

Tags: node.js

Node.js's [website says](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) that the framework "exits the event loop when there are no more callbacks to perform."

What I haven't found clearly explained anywhere is what keeps the event loop running once you initiate an I/O module that is waiting for input. For example, in this canonical "Hello World" HTTP server example, Node.js continues listening indefinitely for incoming HTTP requests:

```
require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080);
```

While there is always the *potential* for a callback to the implicit `request` event handler, until an actual HTTP request comes in, there's no event being handled. Does this mean that the statement from the Node.js website isn't strictly true? Or is there some nuance here that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The nuance is that there are callbacks "under the hood" as well.

In this case, the HTTP server is waiting for incoming connections on a TCP port, and until that port is explicitly closed (`server.close()`), this adds to the list of pending callbacks.

You don't even have to define a request handler to demonstrate this:

```
require('http').createServer().listen(8080);
```

And this shows what happens when you close the port after a few seconds:

```
var server = require('http').createServer().listen(8080);

setTimeout(function() {
  server.close();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: That's basically what I expected, but is that "under the hood" processing for incoming connections really using callbacks? I just dug through the source code for the HTTP library back to the TCP C++ wrapper and I'm not seeing anything that looks like a true callback. Does the event loop also wait for open resource handles to close in addition to callbacks?

Comment: @ScottSB I think that "callbacks" is a confusing term in this situation, as it's easy to think that this means a JS callback function, which isn't necessarily the case. "I/O handlers" may be better. I _think_ that a resource handle that's just open wouldn't block the process from exiting, only when there's an active handler using that resource.